# Sort emails sent from shared mailbox to that shared mailbox's "Sent" folder

Tags: outlook-2007

Basically I'm looking for the exact functionality of this program [UniSent](http://www.ivasoft.biz/unisent.shtml) (description below), except free.

Suppose that Outlook user John Doe has access to his personal mailbox and to the additional mailboxes (usually "Info" , "Sales"  etc.) on Exchange server. When he replies to or forwards from these mailboxes the message goes into his primary mailbox Sent items folder. 
This utility ensures that the message sent with the second mailbox's From address stay in the mailbox that it originated from (i.e. the sent message goes to Sent Items folder of the mailbox the item was sent from).
Also you can easily see who was the original author of the message.

Does anybody know if such a product exists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Other than Unisent, I don't think so. What doesn't Unisent do that you are trying to solve? I might have a workaround that ends up being the same thing.

If all the e-mail addresses were associated with one user (i.e., one mailbox), sales@ info@ and username@, you could do this: First, for incoming mail, you could use a rule that would send it to whatever folder you wanted based on the e-mail address it was addressed to.

Then you could install a product called Choose From for Exchange. It is not too expensive for a server product, but allows you (covers all users, not a per user product) to send e-mails from any e-mail address that is yours. You could then set up another rule to move sent mail to a "sent" folder of your choosing (not the real sent folder, but one that segregates it) based on the From.

Funny, when I clicked on the link for Unisent, and it is the same guy. He is very good with Exchange utilities.

http://www.ivasoft.biz/
http://www.ivasoft.biz/choosefrom2007.shtml

Comment: You can send from any email alias associated with your mailbox in Exchange using the built-in functionality of Outlook.  You just need to add the "from..." field to your new message and specify the address.

Comment: Cheekaleak, your answer is partially wrong: You can pick that when you are sending as another user in the GAL, for which you have send as permission, but not for one of your alternate e-mail addresses. It bounces saying you do not have permission, and you cannot specify the send as permission to a specific e-mail address already associated with your own account, just for an entire mailbox and the primary e-mail address.